# Check if string has a specific word

Tags: java, string

My `String words` contains a bunch of words separated by a `\n` (and ends in an `\n`).
The code adds words to the string, only if the word isn't already there. These blocks of code are within a `for` loop, with `w` being the word to add.

I have

```
loop: if (w.contains("" + letter)) //This is just to test the words I want to add
{
  for (String s : words.split("\n"))
    if (w.equals(s))
      break loop;
  words += w + "\n";
}
```

And

```
if (w.contains("" + letter))
{
  if (!words.contains("\n"+w+"\n") && words.indexOf(w+"\n") != 0)
    words += w + "\n";
}
```

But both seem messy in their own ways. Is there another way to go about this, or which method would perform more quickly.

Comment: Does that code do what you intend to do?

Comment: The code does as it should, and letter was a char, so I converted it to String.

Comment: you can use regex is you prefer. if the code works and you want to refactor it, then you're probably better off posting at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @user1778856.. So, you are saying that, you are comparing a single character. And if your string contains it, then you don't add it. For e.g.: - `asdf\nasdf\nasf`, for this string, your code will fail, if `w` is a single character. But what you have stated, from that, I would add all the 3 words to the new string.

Comment: Sorry, for words to add to the string, I meant only words that passed the `if (w.contains("" + letter))`. I apologize for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `if` is not a loop. So there is no point in labelling it so as use a labelled break.

Secondly, both of your code isn't really doing, what you said you want to do. Also, I don't understand why are you doing `if (w.equals(s))` this test. And what is `w` used for.

You said:  - `w being the word to add`, but again you are saying that, you will add the words from your string after splitting it on `"\n"`, if it is not already in your `array`. So, you are adding many words, not just one word. Please re-read your post, and edit it if necessary.

---

As per your current problem statement, I would approach it like this: -

- First split your lines on `"\n"` to get an array with individual words.
- I would rather use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` if I want to modify my string on each iteration.
- Now, on each iteration, check whether your `StringBuilder` already contains that `word`. If it does not contains, then append it, else leave it.
- At the end of your loop, print your `StringBuilder` instance.

---

Or, as you are saying, you can also use an `ArrayList` to store your words. Or if, you want `unique` words only, you should rather use a `Set` instead. That would not require you to do the test. It handles the duplicates on its own: -

```
List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();

Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();

for (String s : words.split("\n")) {

    if (s.contains("" + letter)) {

        if (!wordList.contains(s)) {
            wordList.add(s);   // Add to list. 
        }
        set.add(s);   // Add to set.
    }
}
```

And then print your `ArrayList` or `Set` by iterating over either of them.

Comment: For the first block, I used `words.split("\n")` for the `for-each` loop. To check if the array already has the word in it, I used `if (w.equals(s))`. If the word is already there, it breaks the entire if-block completely. Otherwise it makes it to the `words += w + "\n"`.

Comment: @user1778856.. First of all, you never stated, that you want an array here. Secondly, To check whether an array contains a word, you should use `if (array.contains(s))`

Answer (score 1):

I would store the distinct words you are adding in List;

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

void addWord(String word){
    if(!words.contains(word)){
        words.add(word);
    }
}

String listAsString(){
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    for(String word: words){
        buffer.append(word);
        buffer.append("\n");
    }
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: wow, this is exactly what I wrote to do 5 mins before you! lol

Comment: @pawel +1 thinking the same.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use a List

```
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList() ;
// to add
if (w.contains("" + letter) && wordList.contains(w) )
{
   wordList.add(w);
}
//at the end you can append \n
StringBuilder bdr = new StringBuilder() ;
for(String word : wordList)
{
     bdr.append(word).append("\n");
}
String words = bdr.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

// if u r trying to find a word/specific word in a string,this code will definitely help u..

public class findWordFromString {

```
public static void main(String[] A)
{
    String str = "Manhattan is a great company";
    String search = "great";
    boolean flag= false;

// here first split or break the string,based on the space present btween each word
    String[] arr = str.split(" "); 
      for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
     {

        if(arr[i].**equals**(search)) // here,never use == instead of equals()  
        {
          flag = true;
            break;
        }
     }//for loop

        if(flag)
        {
           System.out.println(search+" is present");    
        }else
        {
            System.out.println(search+" is not present");
        }
}//method
```

}//class

Answer (score 0):

How about storing the words in an ArrayList and checking if the ArrayList contains the word before adding it? If the order isn't important then use a Set.

It'll be a lot easier to work with a collection and you can then convert it to a string when you need to display it. for eg:

```
List wordList = new ArrayList();

public void addWord(String word){
    if(!wordList.contains(word)){
        wordList.add(word);
    }
}

public String displayWordsAsString(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++){
        //add this condition if you only want a new line between words and not every time.
        if(i > 0)
            builder.append("\n");

        builder.append(word); 
    }

    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Set<String> words = LinkedHashSet<String>();

if (words.add("" + letter)) {
    // Added.
}
```

which maintains the order of adding the words.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fast way to find the specific word in string. without splitting and looping it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String w = "This\nis\nTesting\nString\nthat\ncontains\nHelloWorld\n";
      String searchingWord = "HelloWorld";
      Pattern pattern= Pattern.compile("("+searchingWord+")");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(w);
      if(!matcher.find())
      {
         System.out.println("Word Not Found");
      }else
      {
         System.out.println("Word Found");
      }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you check whether new words are contained and the delimiter is \n then you will need regular expressions. Relying on contains alone would not add words with are sub-sequences of existing word.

```
public class AddWords {

    public String addWord(final String newWord, final String allWords) {
        String result = allWords;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\n" + newWord + "\n.*");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(allWords);
        if (!m.find()) {
            StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
            buf.append(allWords);
            buf.append(newWord);
            buf.append("\n");
            result = buf.toString();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

To better understand the matter I have added a unit test for that scenario:

```
public class AddWordsTest {
    @Test
    public void addExistingWord() {
        String allWords = "\nfoo\nbar\n";
        String notNewWord = "foo";
        AddWords aw = new AddWords();
        String newAllWords = aw.addWord(notNewWord, allWords);
        Assert.assertEquals(allWords, newAllWords);
    }

    @Test
    //This would fail if you rely on contains!!!
    public void addNewWord() {
        String allWords = "\nfoobar\nbar\n";
        String newWord = "foo";
        AddWords aw = new AddWords();
        String newAllWords = aw.addWord(newWord, allWords);
        String expectedAllWords = "\nfoobar\nbar\nfoo\n";
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedAllWords, newAllWords);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String test = "test";
String test2 = "st";
if (test.contains(test2)) System.out.println("String found");
}
```

Comment: This does not work in the case the original poster is talking about.  If the string is composed of the two words "test" and "string" (i.e. - "test\nstring\n") your test would return true for "st", even though "st" is not one of the full words in the word list.